# Home-made fermented/ cured sausages numbing sensation

Tags: meat, sausages, raw-meat

I have two questions regarding my home made sausages.
1- They were great after the normal time-period, fermented well and were a great taste. Now, after another 2 months, all of them taste strongly perfumed, not nice at all and I have to throw them away. How come?
2- In the beginning a bit, but now a lot, they give me a numb sensation in my mouth. What is causing that?

I used color salt for fermenting and ensuring I wouldn't get botulism, but I believe that never is a guarantee?

Thanks for your answers!

B

Answer (score 2):

[The name or chemical compound responsible for a specific quality of some spices (numbness)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37887/the-name-or-chemical-compound-responsible-for-a-specific-quality-of-some-spices) Should answer your question concerning numbness pretty handily. Eugenol can intensify over time. It just so happens that I have been playing with that particular phenomenon quite a bit lately.

Comment: You've only answered half the question here, and eugenol isn't the only thing that can cause numbing - how do you know that's what's going on here?

Comment: @Jefromi True, I can't *know*, since I don't know if he's got any other ingredients that could be causing it as well, but the comments about it getting more pronounced over time and "heavy perfume" allow me to be pretty darn confident about it. Of course a list of ingredients would be helpful, and I will post a comment to that effect. I can only address that half of the question because I don't have any idea about the other half.